# Is using assembly with container worth it?

Tags: swift, swinject

I am using Swinject for Dependency Injection. I have created a DependencyManager which has a shared instance of container.

```
internal class DependencyManager {
private static let sharedInstance = DependencyManager()

private var assembler: Assembler
private let container: Container

class func getResolver() -> Resolver {
    return self.sharedInstance.assembler.resolver
}

class func getContainer() -> Container {
    return self.sharedInstance.container
}

private init() {
    self.container = Container()
    let assembler = Assembler([
        LoginFactory()
        ])
    self.assembler = assembler
}
```

}

LoginFactory class implements Assembly

```
internal class LoginFactory: Assembly {
func assemble(container: Container) {
    container.register(LSViewModel.self) { res in
        return LSViewModel()
    }
    container.register(LSCoordinator.self, factory: { res in
        let lsc = LSCoordinator(window: AppDelegate.mainWindow!)
        lsc.viewModel = res.resolve(LSViewModel.self)
        return lsc
    })
}
```

}

I read Assembly documentation where it says that it is better used for organization - https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject/blob/master/Documentation/Assembler.md. If I had not been using Assembly then I would have used commands like

```
        DependencyManager.getContainer().register(LSViewModel.self) { _ in LSViewModel() }
    DependencyManager.getContainer().register(LSCoordinator.self, factory: { (res) in
        let lsc = LSCoordinator(window: AppDelegate.mainWindow!)
        lsc.viewModel = res.resolve(LSViewModel.self)
        return lsc
    })
    let lsCoordinator: LSCoordinator = DependencyManager.getContainer().resolve(LSCoordinator.self)!
```

Both the implementations are working as expected, without any crashes. I wonder why Assembly is even an advantage? I am doing the same thing without using Assembly without an overhead.

Answer (score 3):

Benefits of organising your code using `Assembly` will start to out-weight the "no overhead" system once the project gets big enough. One way of keeping your code modularised and reusable is (amongst other stuff):

1. Keep DI code for different features separately
2. Features do not have the knowledge of how the final app is put together (e.g. `DependencyManager`)

IMO 1. is quite intuitive. 2. less so, but is free when using assemblies and gives you a lot of flexibility - for example you might want to reuse the feature in multiple apps (e.g. Networking).

Using assemblies you would have something like

```
let assembler = Assembler([
    LoginAssembly(), // each assembly contains DI code for one feature
    HomepageAssembly(),
    UserProfileAssembly(),
    // ...
])
```

while using the intuitive approach might get quite messy.